# ciclo en python

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un codigo para el cual debo realizar un ciclo o usar alguna función que me permita llenar un array con resultados de operaciones de otro array que pertenece a numpy.
Por ejemplo, tengo un array de tamaño 30000 con diferentes valores, lo que quiero es poder llenar otro array de la siguiente manera.
la posicion cero con la suma de los datos ubicados entre las posiciones 5000 y 5100 del array original, la posición uno con la suma de los datos entre 5100 y 5200 y de la misma manera hasta llegar a la posición 20000. Como puedo hacer algo así? Agradezco la ayuda. O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tengas este tipo de problemas te recomiendo hagas todo el esfuerzo por resolverlo usando las librerias y funciones de Python. Si lo resuelves usando for tendrás un código muy lento y poco eficiente.

La solución em este caso consiste en extraer el arreglo entre 5000 y 20000. Luego cambiar el shape Para que cada columna contenga 100 datos. Finalmente hacer la sumatoria en el eje de las columnas (eje 1).

```
import numpy as np

# este sera el arreglo que tiene los 30000 datos
arreglo = np.random.uniform(-1,1,30000)
# este arreglo tendra la salidas de las sumas
salida = arreglo[5000:20000].reshape((-1, 100)).sum(axis=1)
# esto es solo para comprobar el tamaño
print(salida.shape)
# esto para comprobar efectivamente haga lo que deseas
print(salida[0], arreglo[5000:5100].sum())
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.